# Java FileNotFoundException when trying to read txt file from resources folder

Tags: java, resources

I'm trying to read a text file located in `src/main/resources/test/file.txt`. I'm trying to get the path of the file using `String path = getClass().getResource("/text/file.txt").getFile();` but when I try to read it I get a FileNotFoundException. I tried putting many different paths, all of which failed. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: In general, execution do not take place in the sources directory. You have at least to set up your IDE such that it will consider your file as a resource (it may then copy it the a correct location during deployment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of putting something into the src/main/resources tree is that it will be copied into the JAR file that you build from your project.  It will then be available to your application via the `Class` methods `getResource(String)` and `getResourceAsStream(String)` methods.

When you are running in your application in the development environment, it is certainly *possible* to use `FileInputStream` etcetera to access the resource.  But this won't work in production.  In production, the resources will then be *inside* your app's JAR file.  `FileInputStream` cannot open a JAR file and its contents *by name*.

When you do this:

```
 getClass().getResource("/text/file.txt");
```

you get a URL for the resource, which will look something like this:

```
 jar:file:/path/to/your.jar!/text/file.txt"
```

It is not possible to turn that into a pathname the `FileInputStream` will understand.  Whatever you try will give you a `FileNotFoundException` ... or something that is not the resource you want to read.

So what to do?

You have a few options, depending on your application's requirements.

1. You can use `getResourceAsStream` and use the resulting input stream directly.
2. You can copy the contents of `getResourceAsStream` to a temporary file, and then use the pathname of the temporary file.
3. You can create an application specific directory (e.g. in the user's home directory) and extract the file you need from the JAR into the directory.  You might do this the first time the application runs.
4. You could open the JAR file as a `JarFile` and use that API to open an `InputStream` for the resource.  But this assumes that that the resources are in a JAR ... and on some platforms (e.g. Windows) you may encounter problems with file locking.  (And it would be a bad idea to attempt to *update* the resource in the JAR.)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving complete path of the file from the disk.

C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\file name with extension

Comment: Giving an absolute path works, But I'm guessing that won't be effective when I compile.

Comment: The best you can get this way is the pathname of the resource file in your development environment.  It doesn't solve the OP's problem.